# Login failed due to read a double slash instead of only one slash in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, authentication, backslash

I am trying to connect SQL Server to my jupyter notebook (Anaconda). However, I am having some problems due to "".

To create the connection, I am following the steps described in the section "Connecting to SQL Server using pyodbc" of this site https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-easy-button-microsoft-sql-server-and-python#%23client-driver-installation .
These are the steps beginning you can find in the site above: [steps to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQiBz.png)

My problem is that my username and the server name contain "" that python reads as "\". Due this, it returns the error "Login failed for user".

Of the solutions I found, none worked for me.
Considering this example " username = 'user\name' ", these were my attempts:

[My attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEQ4O.png)

Can you help me to find the way I can save correctly these variables which will be used in the final step of connecting to SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a UID containing \ or @ characters then it sounds like you're trying to login using SQL Login authentication but with Windows (or Active Directory) credentials. That's not going to work, you need to use "Integrated Authentication"

Comment: To login, I used Windows Authentication. What's  the "Integrated Authentication"? How should I use it in my case?